# Base Entity and Serializable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can I create something like

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity  implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
}
```

And use it in children class?

Is it ok use one serialVersionUID for all children entities?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse advices to declare new serialVersionUID for my Contract entity extended from BaseEntity with serialVersionUID.

So i think it will be good if you declare it for all child entities.

[image: eclipse advice serialVersionUID]

by the way you can use same serialVersionUID for all your classes.

additionally good writing about serialVersionUID

http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/use-serialversionuid/